# script and css functions only on the first page of tumblr

Tags: javascript, css, tumblr

i have a tumblr page, with infinite scrolling activated and some posts (photos) on it. There is a script that randomizes the posts, but it only works on the posts, that are appearing on the firs page (so, when the scroll takes the posts from the second page the script si not working anymore). Also, there is a css hover effect on the posts, that displays the post title, but this is also woring on the posts from the first page.

What can I do for the script and the css to work on the whole length of the page.

Here is the page: https://www.vul-ne-ra-bil.ro/

And here is the script that shuffles the posts:

```
function shuffle() {
    var tiles = $(".photo:not('.shuffled')");
    for(var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++){
        tiles[i].addClass('shuffled')
        var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length -1) + 1;
        var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * tiles.length -1) +1;
        tiles.eq(target).before(tiles.eq(target2));
    }
}

$(document).ready(shuffle);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are binding the shuffle action to jQuery's `$(document).ready()` which is invoked once when the document finishes loading. InfiniteScroll libraries generally work by querying the next page via `AJAX` and loading the results into the existing page. This won't trigger a `ready()` callback so the shuffle code is not invoked for any page that is loaded by the script.

To fix this behavior, look into whether your infiniteScroll library of choice supports adding callbacks. You could then execute the shuffle function after the script is done loading the next page, e.g. `onNextPage(shuffle)`. I cannot add a snippet to the answer as you did not state how you implemented infinite scroll.

The same goes for the hover if it is bound via JavaScript in an `.ready()` callback.

Relevant links:

- [jQuery ready callback](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [Example of events implemented in a popular inf. scroll library](https://infinite-scroll.com/events.html#load)
- [jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)